# Can I force someone to leave my city?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My quiet little town has run into some trouble. Recently, I tried building my third bridge only to be informed that a citizen's home was too close to the build site.

Upon closer inspection, I learned that my problematic home belonged to Buck, my steroid-fueled donkey. I've never been a big fan of Buck and his sporty attitude, so I'm not overly concerned with him no longer being a citizen in my town. For the greater good.

**How can I remove this steroid-injected donkey and his pesky house?**

Comment: What does the "problematic citizens" option do? There's an option like that at the main menu

Comment: I tried that last night. All Isabelle did was say she'd talk to them to get them to curb their behavior.

Comment: @BenBrocka I believe that option resets their catchphrases and the like.

Comment: I used to just hit them with my bug net a ton which enrages them. Not sure if that causes them to move out but couldn't hurt. Might want to be careful though if he is all roided up.

Comment: @Emerica Definitely don't mess with Coach then.

Comment: Also, pushing them around will piss them off as well.

Comment: Get the megaphone and call their name when they're right next to you, it's quite funny!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no straight up way to "make" an animal leave your town, but you sure can convince them!

The way I understand it, the reason animal stay is based on how close they are to you freinship-wise. If you're a jerk to them, they'll be more likely to leave. Here are some things you can do to make them like you less:

- Hit them with your net repeatedly. They will get upset after 3 hits and not want to talk to you
- Refuse to give them medicine if they are sick.
- Open an item/letter they give you to deliver, especially when they specifically ask you not to
- Deny their requests
- Fail their requests
- Ignore them for long periods of time
- Open time capsules that animals requested you to bury

One thing that does NOT work, but is commonly suggested is reporting them to Isabelle. The options are "I don't like their language", "They have a rude letter", and "Her clothes are wrong". This is because of the customization aspect of Animal Crossing: New Leaf, where people can customize catchphrases, clothing, and write letters. Because of the possibility for harmful content via animals from other towns moving to yours (I've had this happen once before). Isabelle will then remove whatever offensive material they had and replace it with something generic.

I know this to be the case, because a chicken in my town was walking around in a shirt I designed. For fun, I told Isabelle her clothes were wrong. The next time I saw her, she was wearing her default outfit!

Hopefully this list helps :)

Comment: I wish mailing them garbage would still work.

Answer (score 2):

In New Leaf, hitting them with shovels and nets, pushing them around etc? Isn't very effective anymore. Your best bet is to simply *ignore* them, for they sometimes will outright refuse to leave until you become better friends with them - which would be your cue to ignore them completely. In previous games, if you wanted them to move, you would ignore them when they wanted to talk to you, right? Well it's actually best to talk to them. Just decline if they ask you to do something, but never walk away, for they might be telling you they're moving.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes animals just decide to leave. When they talk to you and say this, there are two options: "Don't go!" and "Bye" or something meaning the same thing. Say bye if you want them to leave. If they ask you how their outfit looks, say "Meh..." or something offensive. Whenever they ask you a favor, either open the package, or don't do it. Hitting them on the head with a net works. Also talk to them again and again because they get annoyed. Use pitfall seeds right in front of them so they fall in! Never send them a letter even if it's mean because the animals love letters and probably won't care for what's written in the letter. Push them around by walking in to them continously and don't stop for maybe 30 seconds or less and they get really mad. Never let them come to your house, never give them anything. Eventually they will pack their bags and leave, then tell you that they are moving (see first 3 sentences). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Push them around (30 seconds or more), hit them with your net (over 3 times). Also either never talk to them (or send letters) , or talk to them too much. If they ask to come to your house, always say no, as well as if they ask you to do anything (fish, bugs, clothes, fruit, ect). Try digging holes all around them when stood still, or outside their house. The Isabelle thing dosen't work. I'm not sure this one will work, but try it. If you have the cafe (and a part time job-have coffee 8 times) when they come in, give the opposite of everything they order.
This worked for me with Cyrano, hope it helps!